# @ControllerAdvice is not handling exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have gone through all the related posts but my @ControllerAdvice does not seem to be handling the custom exception that is thrown form the Controller Class.But the   @ExceptionHandler inside the @Controller class does handle the exception though.I have no idea what is the mistake.

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">    
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller,com.test.exception"/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

@ControllerAdvice Class:

```
package com.test.controller;
import com.test.exception.EmployeeException;

@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice         
public class EmployeeExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(EmployeeException.class)
public ModelAndView employeeNotFound(EmployeeException ex){

    String msg="employee with the "+ex.getId()+" not found";
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("helloWorld");
    mv.addObject("message",msg);
    mv.addObject("name","boss");
    return mv;
   }

}
```

The @ControllerAdvice is in the same package as the controller.

Comment: So you do you have `@ExceptionHandler` at both the controller level as well as in `@ControllerAdvice`, then the more specific one will be selected - the one in the controller. If you do not have the one in the controller, then yes we will need to explore more on why it is not getting called - can you please clarify this too. Also `@EnableWebMvc` should be on a class annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: I have ExceptionHandler only in the ControllerAdvice class and i have removed EnableWebMvc annotation.

Comment: Can you please add your controller code in the question? Which spring framework version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement "Ordered" to your @ControllerAdvice exception and return the order using getOrder method of the Ordered interface.

The lower the order the higher the priority. This way you can first capture your response entity exceptions and handle them before they get captured by the global exception handler.

Comment: There is no need of Order annotation unless there are multiple controller advices.